# Ruby: How can i extract just one MYSQL record in Ruby instead all with each_hash do

Tags: mysql, ruby

I know how to get all Mysql Results from a table and output it with each_hash.do in Ruby like this

```
results = con.query "SELECT * FROM table"

#results.each_hash do |row|
  $url = row["Url"]
  $name = row["linkname"]
  $id = row["ID"]
  #end
```

But how can i get only one record extracted from results?

Comment: Answer to your question is below but also, you probably don't want to prefix your variables with `$` as this makes them [global variables](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fetch_hash` on the result.

e.g.

```
results = con.query "SELECT * FROM table"
record = results.fetch_hash
url = record["Url"]
# etc
```

There is also `fetch_row` which returns an array of the field values instead of a hash.

Answer (score 0):

add a "limit 1" to your query? Or break out of the each_hash loop after the first :)